# Probability of drawing the same integer from a set in the first N attempts

Tags: probability

I would like to know:

- Having a universe of numbers from 1 to 10000
- Having made, for instance, 400 draws

How to calculate:

- the probability that there is at least one repeated draw, e.g. that among those 400 the number 3072 appears more than once
- the amount of duplicates to expect, something like 'there is a 95% probability that, between 30 and 50 times, the number drawn will already have been drawn before'.

Thank you. I am sorry for asking questions I should know the answer to, but I just got confused about the issue.

Comment: Exactly twice or more than once?

Comment: It might be easier to reverse the questions, so look at (a) the probability that *every* number drawn is unique, and (b) the distribution of the number of unique numbers drawn

Comment: @drhab more than once

Comment: Please see Wikipedia, Birthday Problem.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you're right, it's exactly the same problem. My question now is how to compute the numbers... given it involves factorials and 10000 is quite a bit higher than 365!

Comment: The article discusses good approximations. The problem is an important one, in discussing hashing and other database problems. Expectations are also discussed.